# Visual Studio 2019 - Angular 9.1.9 - no live reload

Tags: visual-studio-2019, angular9, livereload

I have an angular project that is **launched through IIS with visual studio**

modifying the code does not reload the page while it's working fine from the command line when using "npm start"

**I need it to run from visual studio through IIS for technical reasons**

if I go to the **ClientApp** folder and do **"ng build"**, then **CTRL+F5** in Chrome, the page is updated

is it a bug or is there something to enable somewhere ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\...\myapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\myapp.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like http-server and watch.

Install the http-server and watch via npm globally:

```
npm install -g http-server watch
```

watch will scout for file changes in your directory. If a change is happening it will execute the given command and this one uses the http-server to reload the page.

You can edit watch and http-server then in your package.json

Comment: maybe this documentation can help you also a bit with using watch.
[click me!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.2#run-net-core-cli-commands-using-dotnet-watch)

Comment: ok but are the angular projects generated by VS2019 not supposed to do so ?
pretty sure it was working, maybe its because I updated from v7 to v9

Comment: when I was working with VS2017 and later on with VS2019 I always had the issue with no live reloading to be honest. Also worked with angular 6 and 7. 

still hope that my answer will help you out! :)

Comment: apparently there is no way to run this with IIS